# Cross compiling and Using custom dll with SDL undefined reference to MainWin@16 issue

Tags: bash, gcc, dll, sdl, cross-compiling

What I'm trying to do is pretty complicated, so I'm really a hard time even trying to explain all the problem properly, so, please, be patient ^^ and let me know if you need more information, i'll privede it right away.

---

I'm building a cross-platform library called using SDL2 -and another few things- up to now, from linux I could compile for linux, win32 and win64 using a configure file. (I was using a make file, but a needed a configure file anyway to build the different makefiles, so I decided to put all in the configure file, even the gcc comands -I don't think it is a problem but... who knows ^^).
This discutions "bash script VS makefile" is very useful for me, but that's not the main point here.

Here is the piece of the code that compiles the library:

```
makerfile_l2w()
{
    if [ $1 = "-64" ]; then
        local CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
    elif [ $1 = "-32" ]; then
        local CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
    fi

    local CFLAGS="-O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wmaybe-uninitialized"
    local PREPATH=".."
    #Path to the SDL, SDL_image and Lua includes and libs
    local SDL2INCLUDES="-I $PREPATH/SDL2/include"
    local SDL2LIBS="-L SDLlibs/ -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2"
    local SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES="-I $PREPATH/SDL2/SDL_image"
    local SDLIMAGE2LIBS="-L$PREPATH/SDL2/4windows/SDL2_image/${1:1} -lSDL2_image"
    #LUAINCLUDES = -I $DS(PREPATH)/lua/
    #LUALIB = -L $DS(PREPATH)/lua/ -llua -lm
    #Where to put the compiled program
    local COMPILEPATH="$PREPATH/BINARIES"


    echo "Makefile for linux to windows ${1:1} bits..."
    for file in ./*.c
    do
        set -x
        $CC $CFLAGS $SDL2INCLUDES $SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES -fPIC -c $file $SDL2LIBS $SDLIMAGE2LIBS
        set +x
    done
    mv -v ./*.o $PREPATH/BINARIES/
    set -x
    $CC $CFLAGS $SDL2INCLUDES $SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES -shared $COMPILEPATH/*.o -o $COMPILEPATH/libNLF.dll $SDL2LIBS $SDLIMAGE2LIBS
    set +x
}

makerfile_l2w -32 #I'm calling it like this
```

PS.: I'm trying to build the librarie to 32 bits, I haven't tried it for 64 yet, but I pretty sure I'll have the same issue.

Here is the content of the SDL library directories:
[image]

[image]

I don't know if it's a clue but, when running the script above I repititively this warning:

> warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
> [enabled by default]

Here is an example of the command this script generate to the compiler:

> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable
> -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wmaybe-uninitialized -I ../SDL2/include -I ../SDL2/SDL_image -fPIC -c ./NLF_animation.c -L ../SDL2/4windows/SDL2/32 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main
> -lSDL2 -L ../SDL2/4windows/SDL2_image/32 -lSDL2_image

Here is the command this script generate to build the dll:

> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable
> -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wmaybe-uninitialized -I ../SDL2/include -I ../SDL2/SDL_image -shared ../BINARIES/NLF_animation.o ../BINARIES/NLF_error.o ../BINARIES/NLF.o
> ../BINARIES/NLF_osservice.o ../BINARIES/NLF_screen.o -o
> ../BINARIES/libNLF.dll -L ../SDL2/4windows/SDL2/32 -lmingw32
> -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -L ../SDL2/4windows/SDL2_image/32 -lSDL2_image

After that, I've copied the libNLF.dll file into the directory here I was trying to simulate a program who uses my library, and compile it.
I also, have a script for that, but since a was having trouble, I decided to compile it manually first. Here's the commands I'm using.

> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O3 -I ../../SDL2/include/ -I
> ../../SDL2/SDL_image/ -I ../../NLF_SCR/ -c teste.c -o teste.o

it works fine, the .o file is apparently correctly created...
then this:

> i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-R -Wl,./ -O3 -I ../../SDL2/include/ -I
> ../../SDL2/SDL_image/ -I ../../NLF_SCR/ teste.o main.c -o main.exe -L
> ./ -lNLF

which give me the error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):
> na função 'main':
> /build/buildd/mingw-w64-3.1.0/build/i686-w64-mingw32-i686-w64-mingw32-crt/../../mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: referência indefinida para `WinMain@16' collect2: error: ld returned 1
> exit status

As far as I know, the WinMain() is needed by windows (always windows ¬¬') to do some GUI stuff for GUI application. But the SDL_main.h should take care of this! So it may indicate that some linking is not correct when I built libNLF.dll

Then a changed my "int main()" for "int WinMain()" just to test it, 'cause even if it works it is not a solution to me, I need the application to be as portable as possible. After this change, it worked, but gave me this warnings:

> Warning: resolvendo _WinMain@16 vínculo para _WinMain
>
> Use --enable-stdcall-fixup para desabilitar estes avisos
>
> Use --disable-stdcall-fixup para desabilitar estes fixups

I tried test it with wine run, runnin "wine main.exe", but which gave my a lot of errors like this:

> fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW(L"\\.\DISPLAY1",0,0x61f98c,0x00000000), stub!

But I suspect that this particular message is due some specific wine isse, like a missing 32bits libraries or something...

just in case, here is how the test directory is:
[image]
I got so confused about what librarie I'll need to run the final application that a decided to put everything there, and when it finally works, I research that ^^

FINALLY, THE QUESTION! What am I doing wrong?! How to get away with this WinMain() annoying trouble?

Comment: [Link with SDL2main](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27WinMain.4016.27.22) or define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED before including any SDL headers in a file that defines `main`.

Comment: 1º - I'm already linking all SDL2 stuff when creating the libNLF.dll. So shouldn't all that sutff be handled when I link this library with the final application? - correct me if I'm wrong, please.
2º - I tryind that anyway, compiling de app like this:
`i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-R -Wl,./ -O3 -I ../../SDL2/include/ -I ../../SDL2/SDL_image/ -I ../../NLF_SCR/ teste.o main.c -o main -L ./ -lNLF -L ../../SDL2/4windows/SDL2/32/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lmingw32 -mwindows`
Got the same undefined reference to WinMain@16 =/

Comment: `-lNLF -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, in that order.

Comment: NO KIDDING! -.-' ¬.¬' so much time wested, for this?! T_T kkkkkkkk
Thank you man, that solved the problem =]
The errors when I try to run it on wine remains, but, as I said, I think it's some specific wine issue.
But I still have a question. I still need to relink SDL tuff on the application. Is there a way to "inbuilt" the SDL libraries into mine, or the static linking will bring me some trouble?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do so, exactly because of `SDL2main` part. With your own `WinMain` - sure, that should go fine, if you don't do any SDL calls directly but only through your library. So/dll have dependencies list, but it is runtime, not linking time.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Very helpful information. I know how to solve it. As the saying goes "all the way around" =)